# Want to replicate this graph and don't know packages to get started ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

[image: pH graph]

Want to replicate this graph and don't know packages very well to get started drawing. Please any direction would help.

Comment: Do you have the function expressions for the curves?

Comment: No, I use to draw it with sketch app.

Comment: Ok, so you just need something similar. You might get a complete example from someone, if you want to get started yourself I'd recommend you first look at [the TikZ manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), and study the tutorials in chapter 2 (and maybe 3). The examples are not exactly the same as what you want, but you can use some of the techniques described there to do most if not all of your image.

Comment: I have been there but no clue...

Comment: Data Visualization will set up axes and convert arbitrary units to screen coordinates.  Without formulas, you will have to draw the rest one line at a time.

Comment: Not even for the axis? The first tutorial shows one way of making an axis with ticks and labels.

Comment: See http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pc/pst-dosage/  for similiar curves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try it...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[thick,->] (-1,0) --(7.5,0) node[anchor=north east] {$V_A(mL)$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,-1) --(0,7.5) node[anchor=east] {$pH$};


\draw [color=gray, dashed] (0,4.2) -- (2,4.2);
\draw [color=gray, dashed] (2,0) -- (2,4.2);
\draw [color=gray, dashed] (0,3) -- (4,3);
\draw [color=gray, dashed] (4,0) -- (4,2);
\draw [color=gray, dashed] (0,2) -- (4,2);

\draw (0,6.5) to [thick, out=0,in=90] (4,3);
\draw (0,5.3) to [thick, out=270,in=180] (2,4.2);
\draw (2,4.2) to [thick, out=0,in=90] (4,3);
\draw [thick] (4,3) -- (4,2);
\draw (4,2) to [thick, out=270,in=180] (7,0.2);

\node at (2,0) [below]{10};
\node at (4,0) [below]{20};

\node at (0,6.5) [left]{13.0};
\node at (0,5.3) [left]{11,1};
\node at (0,4.2) [left]{9,2};
\node at (0,3) [left]{7,0};
\node at (0,2) [left]{$pH_{\epsilon2}$};

\node at (-0.2,-0.3) {0};

\node at (2,4.2) {\textbullet};
\node at (4,2) [right]{$E_2$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here a PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,15)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,0)(10,15)
\psplot[algebraic]{0}{10}{-14/(1+Euler^(-x+5))+14}
\rput[l](1,12){$f(x)=\frac{a}{1+\rm{e}^{-x+b}}+c$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

These kind of curves also follow some mathematical functions.

Here: `a=-14`, `b=5`, `c=14`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can always draw a smooth plot through a set of sample points and then use the `intersections` library to mark some special points.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (0,6.5) |- (9,0);
\draw[thick,name path=upper] plot[smooth] coordinates 
{(0,5.7) (2,5.4) (3,5.28) (3.5,5.2) (3.8,5) (4,4) (4.1,2) (4.3,1) (5,0.8) (8.2,0.7)};
\draw[thick,name path=lower] plot[smooth] coordinates 
{(0,4.7) (1,4.2) (2,4) (3,3.8) (3.8,3.6) (4,3.3)};
\path[name path=vert1] (2,0) -- (2,6);
\draw[name intersections={of=lower and vert1}] (2,-0.1) node[below]{10}
-- (intersection-1);
\path[name path=vert2] (4,0) -- (4,6);
\draw[name intersections={of=upper and vert2}] (4,-0.1) node[below]{20}
-- (intersection-1);
\path[name path=hori1] (0,2.2) -- (6,2.2);
\draw[name intersections={of=upper and hori1}] (-0.1,2.2)
node[left]{pH$_{\varepsilon2}$}
-- (intersection-1) node[circle,fill,scale=0.3,label=right:$E_2$]{};
\path[name path=hori2] (0,3) -- (6,3);
\draw[name intersections={of=upper and hori2}] (-0.1,3)
node[left]{$7,0$}-- (intersection-1);
\path[name path=hori3] (0,4) -- (6,4);
\draw[name intersections={of=lower and hori3}] (-0.1,4)
node[left]{$9,2$}-- (intersection-1) node[scale=0.3,fill,circle]{};
\draw (-0.1,4.7) node[left]{11,1} -- (0.1,4.7);
\draw (-0.1,5.7) node[left]{13,0} -- (0.1,5.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: does `\draw (-0.1,4.7) node[left]{11,1} (0.1,4.7);` should be `\draw (-0.1,4.7) node[left]{11,1} -- (0.1,4.7);` (and the same next code line)?

Comment: Thanks for all effort, I am going to mess around with the code to know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If it can be useful, there is, in French, the pst-dosage package

https://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pc/pst-dosage/